# Crear una matriz de similitud de pares sobre las etiquetas de las filas de un dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero hacer un marco de datos de similitud de pares entre los elementos. Cada elemento tiene etiquetas en la columna `shelves` del dataframe. La puntuación de similitud se basa en las etiquetas del elemento.

Aqui esta `data`:

```
    isbn        title                   author  year            shelves
0   0380795272  Krondor: The Betrayal   Raymond E. Feist    1998    [fantasy, raymond-e-feist, feist, epic-fantasy...
1   1416949658  The Dark Is Rising      Susan Cooper    1973    [young-adult, fantasy, ya, childrens, series, ...
2   1857231082  The Black Unicorn       Terry Brooks    1987    [fantasy, sci-fi-fantasy, series, magic, lando...
3   0553803700  I, Robot                Isaac Asimov    1950    [science-fiction, sci-fi, classics, scifi, sho...
4   080213825X  Four Blondes            Candace Bushnell    2000    [chick-lit, chicklit, chic-lit, contemporary, ...
5   0375913750  Love, Stargirl          Jerry Spinelli  2007    [young-adult, ya, realistic-fiction, romance, ...
6   074349671X  The Tenth Circle        Jodi Picoult    2006    [jodi-picoult, contemporary, chick-lit, adult-...
7   0743454553  Vanishing Acts          Jodi Picoult    2005    [jodi-picoult, chick-lit, contemporary, drama,...
8   0765317508  Aztec                   Gary Jennings   1980    [historical-fiction, historical, history, mexi...
9   0142501085  Marlfox                 Brian Jacques   1998    [fantasy, redwall, young-adult, childrens, chi...
```

Sin embargo, si sé cómo calcular las puntuaciones, no sé cómo agregarlas creando un marco de datos de similitud de pares. Intenté lo siguiente con [tanimoto score/índice de Jaccard](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8Dndice_Jaccard):

```
def tanimoto_score(shelves_1, shelves_2):
    intersection_tanimoto = len([x for x in shelves_1 if x in shelves_2])
    union_tanimoto = len(shelves_1) + len(shelves_2)
    return(intersection_tanimoto/union_tanimoto)

similarity_df = pd.DataFrame() 
# for each line we compare the tags 
for index_1,row_1 in data.iterrows():
    for index_2, row_2 in data.iterrows():  
        similarity_score = tanimoto_score(data.at[index_1,'shelves'],data.at[index_2,'shelves'])
        similarity_df[data.at[index_1,'title'],data.at[index_2,'title']] = similarity_score
```

Y me devuelve `similarity_df` con pares pero solo en los títulos de las columnas:

```
(Krondor: The Betrayal, Krondor: The Betrayal)  (Krondor: The Betrayal, The Dark Is Rising) (Krondor: The Betrayal, The Black Unicorn ) (Krondor: The Betrayal, I, Robot)   (Krondor: The Betrayal, Four Blondes)   (Krondor: The Betrayal, Love, Stargirl) (Krondor: The Betrayal, The Tenth Circle)   (Krondor: The Betrayal, Vanishing Acts) (Krondor: The Betrayal, Aztec)  (Krondor: The Betrayal, Marlfox)    ... (Marlfox, Krondor: The Betrayal)    (Marlfox, The Dark Is Rising)   (Marlfox, The Black Unicorn )   (Marlfox, I, Robot) (Marlfox, Four Blondes) (Marlfox, Love, Stargirl)   (Marlfox, The Tenth Circle) (Marlfox, Vanishing Acts)   (Marlfox, Aztec)    (Marlfox, Marlfox)
0 rows × 100 columns
```

Me gustaría obtener:

```
                      Krondor: The Betrayal   The Dark Is Rising ...
Krondor: The Betrayal                     1                 0.75
The Dark Is Rising                     0.75                    1
...
```

Por consiguiente : ¿Cómo crear un dataframe por pares a partir de un dataframe determinado?